# Clustering one or Multi dimensional data with K-Means?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, bigdata

I am working on a dataset from BigData Challenge.

https://dandelion.eu/datamine/open-big-data/
Dataset : Telecommunications - SMS, Call, Internet - MI

sample-dataset(for one day)

```
Square id   Time interval   Country code    SMS-in activity SMS-out activity    Call-in activity    Call-out activity   Internet traffic activity

1   1.39E+12    39  0.11098917  0.166214369 0.10920186  0.164427059 13.64843792

1   1.39E+12    46                  0.026137424

1   1.39E+12    39  0.165136827 0.176399458 0.030875085 0.027300465 13.33085819

1   1.39E+12    0   0.029087775 0.027300465         

1   1.39E+12    39  0.186451092 0.136587823 0.05460093      11.32955226

.

.

10000 1.39E+12  39  0.165136827 0.176399458 0.030875085 0.027300465 13.33085819
```

In this dataset, Milan city geographical area is divided in 10,000 squares id and they have given user activity(SMS,CALL,INTERNET) per square id ,like this I have dataset for one month(30 days) of duration.

With this I am trying to cluster this data into three clusters based on user activity like minimum,average and maximum user activity.

I tired using K-Means Clustering algorithm but since my data is one dimensional K-Means is not suitable for this.

Can I  use days and square-ids as a dimension and run K-Means??

Any suggestion on approach or clustering algorithms??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be (or should have been) asked in stats.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never** use an ID column when clustering.

Also, k-means only works when all columns have the same scale. [Please see the answers to this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means).

If you want to integrate geographic proximity into the clustering, I suggest that you carefully customize a method. Have a look at Generalized DBSCAN, which is designed for customization. Never assume that clustering "just works" because most of the time, it doesn't work, unfortunately.

Also, you need to **define your objective beforehand**. What do you want to achieve, and **how do you measure success?** Doing clustering just because you want to do clustering or because you do not know what to do instead is not going to be a success.

As for the data set, it suffers from not really having an objective. The winning entry appears to boil down to the observation that energy consumption is higher where more people are at the time (surprise). Open-ended challenges are really hard to do.

Comment: Thanks Anony-Mousse for explanation, I will check Generalized DBSCAN.
As mentioned in the post I want cluster the square ids as per their user activity, lets say three cluster one with minimum user activity and then Average and Maximum.

Comment: If you want to transform your data, do that first.